# Forgot to submit Record of Purchase card at Narita

Tags: japan, nrt, tax-refunds

Last time I went on holiday to Japan, I bought some souvenirs and took advantage of the Tax-Free exception for tourists. I knew the procedure to follow regarding the paperwork, so as instructed, I planned to leave the Record of Purchase card at the airport before leaving the country. However, once at Narita, due to a set of reasons, I totally forgot about it, and by the time I realised of my mistake, I was mid flight.

All the purchases that I made were legit, and the amount of money that they discounted was minimal (around 2000 yen). My question is: if in the future I go back to Japan, will there be any issue about this when entering/leaving the country (like having to pay a fine or being questioned by customs)?

Comment: I haven't (yet) found anything definitive on this, but scrolling through posts on Reddit and TripAdvisor it seems that this isn't an infrequent occurrence, but it hasn't been a problem for future visits. YMMV

Comment: I made that exact same mistake in December.  The flight attendant at the gate told me not to worry about it.  I think that is because the store also submits some paperwork.